# oauth2.0 invalid request when trying to use refresh token

Tags: oauth2-playground

Used google oauth2 playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
Followed: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Anyone why I am getting invalid request?

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-length: 209
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth ya29.XXXXXXXX

client_id=XXXXXXXXX&
client_secret=XXXXXXXXX&
refresh_token=1/0ffkj5lggn8XXXXXXXXX&
grant_type=refresh_token

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 33
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Reason: Bad Request
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 21:29:55 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting 400 is because you are adding an invalid parameter or missing one.

edit:

i believe from the given data there is an extra header Authorization. This is used in oauth2 only when access_token is passed in header, to make authenticated calls

```
Authorization : Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

while refreshing access_token there is no need to provide the same in header.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#refresh